# trimspool ON is removing space from last column while spooling

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

I am spooling content of a table onto a flat file as pipe delimited with TRIMSPOOL ON Option. The default value of the last column is BLANK SPACE (' '). The trimspool is trimming this value and hence the value becomes NULL and hence validation is not succesful since this column is NOT NULL. Is there any way to solve this without altering the order of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SET TRIMOUT ON` instead of `SET TRIMSPOOL ON` because it does not affect spooled output.The definition below

```
  SET TRIMOUT ON

Determines whether SQL*Plus allows trailing blanks at the end of each
displayed line. ON removes blanks at the end of each line, which may
improve performance especially when you access SQL*Plus from a slow
communications device. TRIMOUT ON does not affect spooled output.
```

OR you can use `NVL(col_last,' ')` while loading the data